# How do I call upon a separate embed file, and then command it?

Tags: javascript, export, embed

Sorry for the noobiness of this question.

I currently have a Discord.RichEmbed stored in a separate file called embed01.js
which is stored in my bots main directory.

I would like to call it into the bot and then place a command for a user to be able to see it.

I am struggling to make sense of the exports functions and require some help please.

For this example my prefix is "!"

A typical user inputs : !crew
Bot replies with the said embed file and shows it to the user.

Currently I have the code sitting in my main.js, and i would like it out of there, in it's own file and still work.

Basically I would like this below to work, but calling the embed from a file, rather than having the code in my main.js.

```
if(command === "crew") {
message.channel.send;
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("Crewman Title goes here")
.setColor(0x663399)
.setDescription("Description here")
.setFooter("Footer goes here")
.setThumbnail("URL of image here")
.addField(`name part' , 'value part')


message.channel.send({embed});
```

I am an open book, please feel free to ask me for any further info that may be required in order to help me.

Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: Sorry again, I have forgotten to mention this is for a discord.js bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `module.exports` to export the content of your seperate file.

embed01.js:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 
const config = require("./config.json");

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()   
// richembed content ... 
module.exports = (embed);
```

Main.js:

```
    //top of your main.js 
const embed = require('./embed01.js') 
    //your if query for your cmd
if(command === "help2") {
        let richembed = require('./embed01.js');
        message.channel.send({embed: richembed}); 
}
```